# using a datatable's column values as input to the value of the next column

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

I am using a datatable created from a JPA entity.I need to add a column which will be filled with data from another entity, according to the value of the previous column. I could not map the entities as they are in different datasources.

My solution is:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{entity1ManagedBean.mydatalist}">
<h:column id="c1">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText id="o1" value="Value1"></h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText id="value1" value="#{temp.value1}"></h:outputText>
        </h:column>  
        <h:column id="c2">
             <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText id="o2" value="Value2"></h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText id="Value2" value="#{entity2ManagedBean.MapValuesMethod(temp.value1)}"></h:outputText>
        </h:column>
```

but when i run it i get a `javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: class entity2ManagedBean.MapValuesMethod(java.lang.String)`

When i remove the `temp.value1` input from `<h:outputText id="Value2" value="#{entity2ManagedBean.MapValuesMethod(temp.value1)}"></h:outputText>` and test my MapValuesMethod by setting a String input in the method, it works fine.

So i think the problem is i am not passing the temp.value1 string parameter to the managed bean method. Is this possible somehow?

EDIT:

JSF v2.2, eclipselink, web logic 12c

Managed Bean method:

```
public String getMapValuesMethod(String value1){
       //value1= "some string" (testing method)   
      return sessionFacade.sessionBeanqueryMethod(value1);     
}
```

and the session bean method is a simple query.

as I said, when I test the managed bean method by setting value1="some stringvalue" the method returns correct results from the session bean query.

Comment: I nowhere see a `entity2ManagedBean.MapValuesMethod(String value)` method in java code in your post... [mcve] please... always... And version info (jsf, EL etc)

Comment: @Kukeltje I did not include that because I tested it by setting a string value in the method and worked fine. I am pretty sure the problem is in my .xhtml code. I edited the post with the details you asked for.

Comment: This is not an [mcve] and if you have something that **did** work, also post explicitly (an [mcve]) what it was. I have an idea about the problem but want the code in the question to be explicit for futurer readers And please also state jsf and EL implementation and version info. 'JSF2.2 is just an api version'

Comment: The edit to your java code (and not the xhtml) makes it fail by definition. That is against basic EL. Real getters (according to javabean 'standards') cannot contain parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weblogic 12.2.1.2 supports EL 2.x.--> documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/NOTES/whatsnew.htm#NOTES558). I changed my ManagedBean function from `public String MapValuesMethod(String value1)` to `public String getMapValuesMethod(String value1)` and my .xhtml code from `value="#{entity2ManagedBean.MapValuesMethod(temp.value1)}"` to `value="#{entity2ManagedBean.getMapValuesMethod(temp.value1)}"` which solved the problem.

Comment: That is **weird**, Your initial code (before your edit) should have worked too then... Removing the 'get' part from both your java method and EL in the xhtml should just work... Unless the original code was not your real code and the code you had after the edit was... Then it is logical it did not work and we were chasing ghosts...